# Codeigniter subdomain 404 Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I'm working on a project that is done on this framework. When I try to access a url such as "mysite.com/about", it gives me and an error
 `404 Not found`, 
I tried many .htaccess file on wamp and a live host but the result is the same.
I can Access these file by using "mysite.com/index.php/about" but I want to access as this "mysite.com/about" this not only for about page but all so very page that I try to access by using like this "mysite.com/contact-us"
.How do I fix this?

Comment: do you have controller with name `about??`

Comment: Just a quick check have you named your controller files and class names like what says here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: Add some code  else this should flagged as Unclear

Comment: Please provide the code, especially for the controller

Comment: I can access these file if I use like mysite.com/index.php/about

Comment: Did you enable mod rewrite on wamp. You will need a htaccess file for main directory. And $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: yes I have done both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this code in your .htaccess file and in wamp server click on rewrite_module

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   IndexIgnore *

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this where should I place this .htaccess file on my current folder that  index.php in or in a folder of wamp setting ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Codeigniter will call the **about** controller, unless a method is provided in the second uri segment, the **index()** method will be loaded.

If the **index()** method doesn't exist, it will 404.

The other way of doing it is to add a line in your *application/config/routes.php* file. Such as:

```
$route['about'] = 'main/about';
```

This means, a request where the url matches /**about** will map to **main/about**

**Main** being the controller and **about** being the method within that for example.

See this part of the documentation for a more detailed explaination
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Hope this helps

Comment: This has been changes too 
$route['about'] = 'about/index/$1';

$route['dorms-rooms'] = 'dorms_rooms/index/$1';

like this. this not only for tha about page but to all page I'm trying to access like this "mysite/about"

Comment: Do you have an index() method in your about controller?

Comment: See the 'hello world' example here..  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have named the Class for your controller as the controllers file name. Then try to access the page as shown in the code below.

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {
   
 function about()
 {

        $data['title'] = 'About us Page';
        $this->load->view('about', $data); //about is in views
   }

      }

?>
```

The file name should be pages.php in this case.

To access the about page type in this link mysite.com/index.php?/controllerfolder/pages/about.

If you want clean url and remove `index.php?` edit your `htaccess`. Use this link to know how to edit your htaccess
 https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/.

Hope this is helpful. Thanks

Comment: You do not need to close controllers with `?>`